# How to use tooltip in winapi?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I have tried use tooltip in winapi but it not worked! This is my code, my tooltip doen't show! Can you tell me why it not work? I'm using visual studio 2010.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void CreateMyTooltip(HWND);
HWND CreateToolTip(HWND hDlg, int tooID);
void AddToolTip(int toolID,  PTSTR pszText, HWND hDlg);
HINSTANCE hinst;

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    MSG  msg ;    
    WNDCLASS wc = {0};
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Tooltip" ;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance ;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc2 ;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClass(&wc);
    CreateWindow( wc.lpszClassName, L"Tooltip",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 200, 150, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);  
    hinst - hInstance;
    while( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc2( HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch(msg)  
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateMyTooltip(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

void CreateMyTooltip (HWND hwnd)
{

    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX iccex; 
    HWND hwndTT;                

    TOOLINFO ti;
    wchar_t tooltip[30] = L"A main window";
    RECT rect;                 

    iccex.dwICC = ICC_WIN95_CLASSES;
    iccex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    InitCommonControlsEx(&iccex);

    hwndTT = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,        
        0, 0, 0, 0, hwnd, NULL, hinst, NULL );

    SetWindowPos(hwndTT, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

    GetClientRect (hwnd, &rect);

    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
    ti.hwnd = hwnd;
    ti.hinst = NULL;
    ti.uId = 0;
    ti.lpszText = tooltip;
    ti.rect.left = rect.left;    
    ti.rect.top = rect.top;
    ti.rect.right = rect.right;
    ti.rect.bottom = rect.bottom;

    SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &ti); 
    SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ACTIVATE, true, NULL);
    SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_POPUP, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Add some error checking and try again.

Comment: Program does not compile.

Comment: I still compile success! and not error, just tooltip not appear!

Comment: We've no idea what "not worked" means. Please make more effort to describe what you hope will happen, and what actually happens. Please add error checking. Please learn to debug your code.

Comment: Yes, my happen is i don't send an addtool message to the tooltip control window:  SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &ti);

Comment: Line 29 `hinst - hInstance;` does not compile.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

There seems to be an error with the manifest. If you are using Visual Studio, go to project properties:

Project -> Properties -> Linker -> Manifest -> Generate Manifest file: Yes

Once you have the correct manifest, you can call the function normally:

```
void CreateMyTooltip(HWND hparent)
{
    HWND hwndTT = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hparent, NULL, 0, NULL);

    TTTOOLINFO ti = { 0 };
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TTTOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = hparent;
    ti.lpszText = TEXT("Tooltip string");
    GetClientRect(hparent, &ti.rect);

    if (!SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti))
        MessageBox(0,TEXT("Failed: TTM_ADDTOOL"),0,0);
}
```

You should make sure the manifest is correct. If it's wrong then you can run in to trouble here, and in lots of other places.

---

This is the old answer: **(not recommended!)**

If manifest is wrong, you have to give set the right value for `TTOOLINFO::sbSize` which in my case happens to be `TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE`

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#pragma comment(lib, "comctl32.lib")

HINSTANCE g_hinst;

void CreateMyTooltip(HWND hparent)
{
    HWND hwndTT = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
        WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP, 0, 0, 0, 0, hparent, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);

    TTTOOLINFO ti = { 0 };

    //ti.cbSize = sizeof(TTTOOLINFO);
    //*********************************************************
    // Specific settings for specific compiler options (Unicode/VC2013)
    //*********************************************************
    ti.cbSize = TTTOOLINFOW_V2_SIZE; 

    ti.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = hparent;
    ti.lpszText = TEXT("Tooltip string");
    GetClientRect(hparent, &ti.rect);

    if (!SendMessage(hwndTT, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti))
        MessageBox(0,TEXT("Failed: TTM_ADDTOOL"),0,0);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateMyTooltip(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    g_hinst = hInstance;

    WNDCLASS wc = { 0 };
    wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("TooltipTest");
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    RegisterClass(&wc);

    CreateWindow(wc.lpszClassName, TEXT("Tooltip"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE,
        100, 100, 200, 150, 0, 0, g_hinst, 0);

    MSG  msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Hi Shemirani, i have a question: Can i control appearing and possiton of tooltip?

Comment: @trantuan I updated my answer. Please try to fix your manifest. And then try again with just `ti.cbSize = sizeof(TTTOOLINFO);` That's the correct way. Forget about the earlier answer I gave, it's impossible to keep track of those things manually. If it fixes your problem please accept the answer, click the check mark, to close bring this to a close. Then you can ask a new question.